# Много поддоменов и их связка

Tags: .htaccess, php

Всем привет.
Есть вопрос, кто-то его уже наверное решал или делал что-то подобное.

Голова в последнее время не работает, пора в отпуск наверное.

суть вопроса.

есть адрес

```
somesite.ru/user/vasya/
```

Это как бы его кабинет.

Нужно чтобы было

```
 vasya.somesite.ru тоже самое что и somesite.ru/user/vasya/
```

т.е. при регистрации в системе у пользователя появляется поддомен с его ником. И данные он брал со страницы somesite.ru/user/vasya/

как бы сие дело настроить, кто знает, голова отказывается работать.

Comment: Отлично!  прям в точку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну я бы это решил с помощю ДНС, типа *.somesite.ru A ип-адрес-сайта (т.е. ЛЮБЫЕ поддомены сайта somesite.ru вели на ваш сайт), а уже подддомены обрабатывал скриптом. никаких htaccess... т.о. vsyakaya-fingya.somesite.ru будет вести все равно на ваш сайт, а вы взависимости от запросы будете чтото выводить.

и что значит "И данные он брал со страницы somesite.ru/user/vasya/"? это у вас ЧПУ или физические директории на диске?

Comment: да нет конечно не физические.

Это ЧПУ от htaccess + Yii

ну т.е. набрал он vasya.somesite.ru а в ответ ему на этом домене открылась страница его профиля somesite.ru/user/vasya/ тип того.

Про А запись - это хорошо, это выгодно. ступил однако. :)

Comment: да, если такую систему планируете, то лучше ДНСом решить... я тоже както думал сначала решить такое htaccess, было хорошо, пока дподдоменов было мало, но потом начался геммор с этим) и перенес разбор полетов внутрь скрипта...

Comment: единственно не забыть перенести www и все остальные нужные поддомены до записи *.somesite.ru иначе... ;)